# Ext functors and extensions.

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Given two short exact sequences,

$$ 0 \to A \xrightarrow{f} B \xrightarrow{g} C \to 0 $$
$$ 0 \to B \xrightarrow{\alpha} Y \xrightarrow{\beta} X\to 0$$

I want to show that if the short exact sequence obtained by taking the pushout of the maps $g,\alpha$ is equivalent to
$$C \to X \oplus C \to X $$

then the second short exact sequence is equivalent to the pushout (using $f$) of some sequence of the form
 $$ A \to Z \to X $$

I have been able to prove similar propositions but in this case I don't know how to use the fact that the pushout sequence is trivial. I tried to construct the kernels of the maps of the pushout but I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We start by constructing the following diagram,

[image]

with the left square a pushout diagram. First we need to show that $\operatorname{Ker} \varepsilon \cong A$

Set $ \operatorname{Ker} \varepsilon \xrightarrow{k} Y $, clearly $\beta \circ k=0$ so $k$ factors through the kernel of $\beta$ namely $B$, denote this factorization by $m$. Then one can see that 
$$i_C \circ g \circ m=0 \implies g \circ m=0$$ 
so $m$ factors through the kernel of $g$, that is we can find a map $\operatorname{Ker} \varepsilon \xrightarrow{u} A$ such that $f \circ u =m$. An inverse to $u$ is found via the fact that
$$\alpha \circ f \circ \varepsilon = 0.$$
In the following diagram we want to show that $\gamma$ is an isomorphism this is done with standard diagram chasing with generalized elements.

[image]

Taking the pushout of $f,\theta$ we obtain $P,\chi,\sigma$, and construct the associated exact sequence fitting in the last diagram which is clearly commutative finishing the proof.

[image]